# Matlab - Make Only Part of Axis Title bold

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

i have a 2x2 subplot for data that varies on 2 dimensions- i want a shared title for plots [(1,1) and (1,2)] vs [(2,1) and (2,2)] as well as a shared title for plots
[(1,1) (2,1)] vs [(1,2) and (2,2)]. Separately, i need x and y labels for each of the 4 subplots.

I am working with Matlab R2021a

is there a way to make the shared axis titles bold while keeping each individual subplot axis title not bold?

Thanks so much

Comment: Check the doc [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.layout.text-properties.html) and [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.layout.tiledchartlayout-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

See the [offical document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-TitleFontWeight)

```
ax = subplot(2,2,1);
ax.TitleFontWeight = 'normal';
```